# How to make sure a class is valid before referencing?

Tags: c#, class, validation

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public int? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public int? CarQTY { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to throw an exception if someone doesn't have the object completely populated.  For example, if fullName, phoneNumber, or carQTY is null, I want to throw an exception on the get method.

Do I really have to do this?

```
    public class Person
    {
        string _FullName;
        int? _PhoneNumber;
        int? _CarQTY;

        private Boolean IsValid()
        {
            Boolean condition = true;
            condition = (FullName != null) && (PhoneNumber != null) && (CarQTY != null);
            return condition;
        }
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                if (!IsValid()) throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", "fullName is null");
                return _FullName;
            }
            set
            {
                _FullName = value;
            }
        }
        public int? PhoneNumber
        {
            get
            {
                if (!IsValid()) throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", "phoneNumber is null");
                return _PhoneNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _PhoneNumber = value;
            }
        }
        public int? CarQTY
        {
            get
            {
                if (!IsValid()) throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", "carQTY is null");
                return _CarQTY;
            }
            set
            {
                _CarQTY = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you may make an explicit constructor with the 3 variables, hiding the setters. If you want the setters to be public you may have a boolean for validity

Comment: Yes and No, you could just put the exception into your `IsValid` method. Or force to set the values in the constructor.

Comment: This looks like a job for https://fluentvalidation.net/

Comment: How did you set the data?

Comment: It's a little smelly to me... Not sure the premise of this is sound in 99.9322222222222222222% of instances...

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, forcing to create the object through a constructor is simply the most efficient way:

```cs
    public class Person
    {
        public string FullName { get; private set; }
        public int PhoneNumber { get; private set; }
        public int CarQTY { get; private set; }

        public Person(string fullName, int phone, int carQty){
            FullName = fullName;
            PhoneNumber = phone;
            CarQTY = carQty;
        }
    }
```

The setters might also be public, if you want to allow the modification of the object once it has been created.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this could be a controversial issue in terms of where and how an object should be validated. Should an ***object*** complains if it's not created as it should? Or should the ***creator*** be responsible for checking the integrity of the object is about to create?

I can *digest* let me say the second *should*.

> You want to create me, then create me correctly!

Thus, I'd like to suggest the following:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    //I suggest the PhoneNumber should be a string type.
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int CarQTY { get; set; }

    public Person() { }

    public Person(string fullName, string phoneNumber, int carQTY) : this()
    {
        FullName = fullName;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        CarQTY = carQTY;
    }

    public static Person Parse(string fullName, string phoneNumber, int carQTy)
    {
        if (!TryParse(fullName, phoneNumber, carQTy, out Person person))
            throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect Arguments");

        return person;
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string fullName, string phoneNumber, int carQTy, out Person person)
    {
        person = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber) &&
            carQTy > 0)
            person = new Person(fullName, phoneNumber, carQTy);

        return person == null ? false : true;
    }

    public override string ToString() =>
        return $"{FullName}, {PhoneNumber}, {CarQTY}";
}
```

Now, you have two new static functions (`Parse`, `TryParse`) the caller can use to create  a valid objects. So you can do:

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    private void CreatePerson()
    {
        if(!Person.TryParse(fullName, phoneNumber, carQty, out Person person))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalide Args");
            return;
        }

        //You have a valid person object...
    }
}
```

Or

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    private void CreatePerson()
    {
        Person person;
        try
        {
            person = Person.Parse(fullName, phoneNumber, carQty);
            //You have a valid person object...
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your point, but choosing "Parse" as the function name seems wrong to me. Parsing, is generally used as a synonym of 'transform from' (usually a string). "Create" and "TryCreate" seem more logical to me. Also on `public static Person Parse` you instantiate `Person` twice.