# Return false if type properties equals null or 0

Tags: c#

I tried following the method as follows here: [Checking if Object has null in every property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128815/checking-if-object-has-null-in-every-property) . However, when instantiating `Order newOrder = new Order();`. I cannot simple just implement `bool props = newOrder.ArePropertiesNotNull()`. What am I supposed to add to my Order class? And where do I implement the function for `ArePropertiesNotNull<T>(this T obj)`? I would like to know if there is a way to return false if value returned equals 0 or null?

Here is my code:

**OrderProdRepository.cs**

```
...
public bool ReadFromFile(string _date)
        {
            taxesFile.ReadFile();
            productsFile.ReadFile();

            string orderFileName = $"C:\\tempfolder\\Orders_{_date}.txt";

            List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(orderFileName).ToList();

            foreach (var line in lines.Skip(1)) //?? new List<string>(0)
            {
                List<string> entry = line.Split(',').ToList();

                Order newOrder = new Order();               
                int.TryParse(entry[0], out int orderNumber);
                newOrder.OrderNumber = orderNumber;
                newOrder.Date = _date;
                newOrder.CustomerName = entry[1];
                newOrder.State = taxesFile.StateAbbreviation(entry[2]);
                newOrder.StateName = taxesFile.StateName(newOrder.State);
                decimal.TryParse(entry[3], out decimal taxRate);
                newOrder.TaxRate = taxesFile.TaxRate(taxRate);
                newOrder.ProductType = productsFile.ProductType(entry[4]);
                decimal.TryParse(entry[5], out decimal area);
                newOrder.Area = area;
                decimal.TryParse(entry[6], out decimal costPerSquareFoot);
                newOrder.CostPerSquareFoot = productsFile.CostPerSquareFoot(costPerSquareFoot);
                decimal.TryParse(entry[7], out decimal laborCostPerSquareFoot);
                newOrder.LaborCostPerSquareFoot = productsFile.LaborCostPerSquareFoot(laborCostPerSquareFoot);
                decimal.TryParse(entry[8], out decimal materialCost);
                newOrder.MaterialCost = materialCost;
                decimal.TryParse(entry[9], out decimal laborCost);
                newOrder.LaborCost = laborCost;
                decimal.TryParse(entry[10], out decimal tax);
                newOrder.Tax = tax;
                decimal.TryParse(entry[11], out decimal total);
                newOrder.Total = total;


                orderList.Add(newOrder);
            }
            return true;
        }
...
```

Comment: why do you tend to have a generic solution rather than implement method that validates if order is filled correctly? I see that you have value type properies (decimal, datetime, int) and you cannot just compare them with null. Reflection is very slow comparing to method call with validation method.

Comment: Are you trying to return false if there are no lines in the file? Sorry, it's not entirely clear to me what your desired behavior is.

Comment: value is coming from user and checking values from a list, example `taxesFile.TaxRate(taxRate);` will either return null if not found in the list or returns value if in list. I want to return false if returned null in any property.

Comment: Better to serialize your objects mate. Then you just need to load/save a list of your serializable objects.

Comment: I wish I could understand what you mean by serialize objects, "convert object to byte" ? This is just the read method, there are other functions that do create, update, and delete. Very complex assignment, because user is only allowed to get what is available in a list, so it would be better to return false right away when it finds a value not in list because is too long and have to wait until that last value.

Comment: There has got to be a better way to validate this, just realized that CustomerName is expecting character validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a function to check each line for `null` and/or `0` values:

```cs
private bool IsValidLine(string line)
{
    if (line == null)
        return false;

    var arr = line.Split(',');   

    //Uncomment this if splitting the line will always return 11 items array.
    //if (arr.Length < 11)
    //    return false;      

    return arr.Aggregate(0, (n, s) => 
    (decimal.TryParse(s, out decimal d) && d == 0) || 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? n + 1 : n) == 0;
}
```

You can use it in your code as follows:

```cs
public bool ReadFromFile(string _date)
{
    var orderFileName = $"C:\\tempfolder\\Orders_{_date}.txt";
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(orderFileName);

    foreach (var line in lines.Skip(1))
    {
        //If parsing any line returns false.
        if (!IsValidLine(line))
            return false;

        //Or if you need to create a list of the valid Order entries.
        if (IsValidLine(line))
        {
            var order = new Order();

            //...

            orderList.Add(newOrder);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Alternatives:**

- Add a static function in the `Order` class to *parse* a given line and return a new object of `Order` type if the line is valid. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567899/how-to-make-sure-a-class-is-valid-before-referencing/59569304#59569304).
- If its not too late, then consider using a local database or serialization. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686509/trouble-serializing-and-deserializing-multiple-objects/58687570#58687570) and maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074005/saving-listbox-with-additional-information-in-my-settings/59097544#59097544) if you don't mind a `vb.net` example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create this method an extension method. It should be defined in static class:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{        
    public static bool ArePropertiesNotNull<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperties().All(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(obj) != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no idea the method would not work, unless it is an extension.

Comment: Could I be able to validate a string input with a ObjectExtensions method? For example `newOrder.CustomerName = CharactersValidation(entry[1]);` ?

Comment: @AlejandroH this method is supposed to validate object's properties, it wont work for a simple string